# UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed behavior in Site-Based package?

Tags: userlicense

I'm considering [this workaround](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092XIIAY) to determine whether a class is running in unmanaged or managed context when calling System.requestVersion().

The documentation of UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed defines the method as follows:

> Returns true if the context user has a license to the managed package denoted by the namespace. Otherwise, returns false.

In this case, what does 'License' refer to if I have a site-based package? There are no licenses to assign to users, they'll typically all have access. So if a user of the package has this installed, can the method always be expected to return true for this org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Site-based licenses report "true" for all user contexts. You can test this in a Sandbox to prove this to yourself (all apps installed in Sandboxes have perpetual Site-based licensing).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll definitely test it out, just wanted to see if there were any special exceptions where the behavior would be different.